# onRequestStart user authorisation does not work correctly coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Im my Application.cfc I am trying to use the `onRequestStart()` function to protect my pages as such:

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" access="public" returntype="boolean">
  <cfargument type="String" name="TargetPage" required="true"/>

  <!--- Define which pages don't need protection --->
  <cfset APPLICATION.AllowedPages = "/index.cfm, /register.cfm">

  <!--- Create an instance of the page-protect.cfc --->
  <cfset APPLICATION.PageProtect = CreateObject("component", "page-protect")>

  <!--- check if the current page is an allowed page --->
  <cfif #ListFindNoCase(APPLICATION.AllowedPages, ARGUMENTS.TargetPage)# EQ 0>
  <!--- if its not an allowed page, then protect it --->
  <cfscript>
  APPLICATION.PageProtect.PageProtectBasic(argumentcollection = session); 
  </cfscript>
  </cfif>

<cfreturn true>
</cffunction>
```

This code works (kind of as you will see later). Page-protect.cfc is very simple and does this:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="page-protect" output="false">
<cffunction name="PageProtectBasic" output="no">
  <cfif NOT structKeyExists (SESSION, 'Auth')>
    <cflocation url="/index.cfm" addtoken="no">
  </cfif>
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

So if the `Auth` structure within the `SESSION` scope does not exist, then this user is not logged in and should be taken back the homepage. A logout method in a different file deletes the Auth structure from SESSION and also clears the SESSION scope (if definitely does this I have tested it).

The `onRequestStart()` page protection works initially but I have noticed that when I press the back button on my browser it will show the previous page that I just logged out of. This should be a protected page and not display but I guess its a browser cache so not a problem. However the problem is that if I click on a link in this page it SHOULD not allow it and send the user back to home page (because the SESSION.Auth structure does not exist and SESSION has been cleared). But it does not send the user back to the homepage anymore, it just shows a ColdFusion error page stating that "Element AUTH.{element_name} is undefined in SESSION".

So for some reason its not going back to the homepage despite the user not being logged in, and instead is trying to load the protected page and then falling over because a variable within the SESSION.AUTH structure does not exist. I simply don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Please help!

Comment: I was going to comment about APPLICATION.pageProtect being instatiated on every page request, but James fixed it in his answer. Once again....you are reinventing the wheel. Had you started this project with a framework, I hazard a guess you would be much further along in the process.

Comment: I'm not sure why Page Protect is in its own component. It could be included in your onRequestStart just as easily as the 3 lines fo code it runs.

Comment: You should post this code on Code Review (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as there are a number of things wrong with it outwith the issues already touched on by others here, but not relevant to your question.

Comment: So you're still not using a framework? Sigh. What makes you think - as a newbie - you know better than a number of seasoned professionals?

Comment: @AdamCameron you seem be taking it rather personally that I'm not using a framework? I don't think that I know better than professionals at all. It's because I don't know better that I'm not able to jump into using one confidently. I looked at FW/1 as soon as you and others mentioned it but I didn't like the idea of having an index.cfm file load the entire sites content on the fly using URL variables. Of course that is only one thing I didn't like. If in the future I can have more people working on it, then I'd look into FW/1 again. For now I have get this prototype working for demo purposes.

Comment: @MattBusche its not a finished component yet. i left it that way for flexibility in case I need to do additional work later.

Comment: It's because I think you're wasting an awful lot of your time in NOT using a framework, and you will, as a result, produce sh!t code. The CFML community has an over abundance of sh!t coders, and I (and some of the rest of us) are trying to turn this around. Developers like you give our community a bad name. That's why I'm taking it personally.

Comment: I am not in a CF developer position in any company, so no need to worry that I am spreading my sh!t skills around the community lol. I've been tasked with producing a working prototype that can then be taken on by another team for proper development. This may sound absurd but its the way it has to be done for now. Nobody wants to invest in something that they can't see working in some capacity. Its a very tight deadline so I'm doing my best. CF books are few and far between and don't cover this type of stuff in massive detail from the outset. its mostly inline examples hence the issues.

Comment: BTW, half-way down the first page of the docs for FW/1 describes how to do SEO-friendly URLs: https://github.com/framework-one/fw1/wiki. Although why that should be a consideration on a prototype, I don't know. If you'd used a framework (which would require reading some docs, rather than blundering along) you'd've finished your prototype by now. It's is FAR FASTER to develop prototypes with a framework than without. Your "sh!t skills" *are* being spread around the community already. Via these questions in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well I'm sorry you feel that way but for me to totally rewrite this application using a framework at this stage would mean I'd probably get fired for taking too long. Then that would be one less coldfusion advocate in the community, albeit with sh!t skills. They already wanted to use .NET but I opted for CF so on my head it is.

Comment: Plus I don't see anything wrong in someone wanting to do something themselves rather than using a framework. If someone wanted to make cross-browser compatible Javascript, is everyone going to shout him down because he should just use JQuery or whatever else instead. I think that's slightly unfair.

Comment: What have you done by way of VERIFYING your logic is working how you expect (well: clearly it's not working). Everything you've posted seems to be based just on your expectations, not on actually checking. EG: you're not saying "what's weird is `session.auth` is not being set, but I set it on the previous line", it's more like just "it's just not working and I don't know why". What variables have you dumped out and where? What logging have you done to test your logic? What are the results of your logic at key places in the process?

Comment: If John Resig wanted to make a new cross-platform JavaScript library: no, ppl would not have a problem; if Newbie McIgnorant did? Yeah, everyone would say "FFS, just use JQuery". You should *learn* by using the framework, and see how it works. All you're learning here is how not to do stuff (although I question whether you're actually learning much here). These are valid life lessons, but not an effective way to actually learn in a way that your reserve of useful knowledge and understanding will increase at an effective rate.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you adam, I'm just asking that you cut me some slack because my position does not allow me any time right now to learn a framework. if the prototype works to some extent then great, I will have more time to look at it again properly. for now unfortunately i can only see as far as the next tree rather than the forest so-to-speak.

Comment: I am cutting you slack. I am still trying to help you as well, after all. But every time you post a question wherein the best answer is "you should be using a framework for this", then that's the answer you should expect to get. And if you ask me *why* I say that, then I'll tell you. Plus for the next person who blunders along into this question, they might be in a better position to take heed and *actually stop what they're doing and... **use a framework**!*

Comment: You need to be more directed at the questions you ask. Because you're now asking two different questions here. S/O questions aren't supposed to be an ongoing help line for "let's work through your code together" sort of scenario. Are you submitting the login directly to the CFC? If so, your CFC will need to be in that "AllowedPages" list too. Anything you want the user to browse to without auth will need to be in that last.

Comment: Thanks Adam, it only just clicked with me to do that as well hence I removed my edit. it works now nicely :) when its all finished I'll give you a link to the working prototype so you know what its all about :)

Comment: Coolio. So this whole issue is resolved now, or just that secondary issue? (EDIT: Ah, I see Simon's answer was what you were after. Cool).

Comment: The whole entire issue end-to-end is resolved!

Comment: @volumeone which is it? That you need to know how that application works 100% or that you do not have time to learn a framework? Because those are 2 excuses you have given for not using a framework. I also find it funny (in a sad kind of way) that you feel you do not have enough time to use a framework, but you feel you have enough time to write one. Framework authors have solved just about every issue you have brought up in the last month or so.

Comment: @ScottStroz seriously, if I had time and ability and everything else I would be doing what you are recommending. I am not in a developer position but I am a CF fan and I took it upon myself to make a working prototype to show people. Both my reasons (not excuses) are true. I need to know what I'm doing 100% so I don't look like a d!ck in front of people when things don't work. Using a framework maybe ideal but I can't handle that task right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While James Mohler provides some very helpful pointers on how to improve your code in general the issue you are having is not related to that.

The reason that users can see these pages on hitting back is because they are cached in the browser. This is the browser trying to be helpful and not requesting data from the server that it has already seen. The browser being a good internet citizen will do what it is told though. So you need to return the correct HTTP headers to tell it that you don't want it to cache them. E.g.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
```

So to do this in CF

```
<cfheader name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate">
<cfheader name="Pragma" value="no-cache">
```

If you add the above to the pages that are concerning you, the problem will go away.

Simon

Comment: We do this often enough that we created a custom tag, <cf_nocache>

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, this won't fit into a comment box

I think what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
onApplicationStart()  {

    APPLICATION.PageProtect = CreateObject("component", "page-protect")>
    }


onSessionStart()  {

   session.auth = false; // it is easier to work with if it always exists
   }


onRequestStart()  {


   if (ListFindNoCase(APPLICATION.AllowedPages, ARGUMENTS.TargetPage) EQ 0)
        // if its not an allowed page, then protect it 
        APPLICATION.PageProtect.PageProtectBasic(argumentcollection = session); 
        }


   }
```

Comment: thanks James. I put the CreateObject in the onRequestStart method because I am in development and can't clear the Application scope each time I make a change. Later on I would of course move it to onApplicationStart

Comment: James you should consider using a Gist (https://gist.github.com/) for when you want to reference some code in a comment, but it won't fit (or format nicely).

Comment: Regarding changes to Application variables during development.  In your onRequestStart() method, run the onApplicationStart() method when appropriate.

Comment: I think James did the right thing by posting his code as an answer.  Lazy people like me prefer one stop shopping.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not related to your problem but this line might have a couple of issues.

```
  <cfset APPLICATION.AllowedPages = "/index.cfm, /register.cfm">
```

Issue number 1 is the leading slashes.  Unless arguments.TargetPage has those slashes, and they might, you are not going to get the expected behaviour.

Issue number 2 is the space between your two list items.  Leading spaces are part of the list item which could lead to unexpected behaviour on register.cfm.

Comment: thanks for the tip. the Arguments.TargetPage has the slashes in and so its working correctly. I removed the spaces now so should be good to go. thank you!